# Disabled button doesn't work in React JS if text color is specified

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I would like to specify style(background and text color) of the button that will be disabled later in code.
[button needs to look like this on render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCy4r.png) and [like this after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyUsc.png)

My code is

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button disabled={loading} onClick={handleClick} className="btn">
        {" "}
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and Css

```
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  /* color: white; */
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-https-ghxry?file=/src/styles.css:59-183)

When I specify color of the text(white) disabled doesn't change color to grey( button doesn't look disabled), when text color is not defined, it's black and after click it's grey. Is there any way to define text color as white before click, and when button is clicked change color to grey? Because I need to make the button with blue background and white text on render. Thank you anyone who will help me.

Comment: You should specificy either `:enabled` selector for setting a color when the button is active, or specify a `:disabled` selector for the color when it is disabled, for example, through: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_enabled_disabled

Comment: @ Icepickle , thank you so much, it worked! Can't believe that I was stuck for something that simple)

Answer (score 1):

Most of this can be done with CSS, though you'll need to add one more thing to your React component.

JS:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button disabled={loading} onClick={handleClick} className={`btn${loading ? ' disabled' : ''}`}>
        {" "}
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS

```
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  /* color: white; */
}
.btn.disabled {
  opacity: .65;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn:active {
  color: green; // Or whatever style you want
}
```

EDIT: You can also use the :enabled and :disabled pseudo-selectors like the comment above said.